# MVC5 EF Save in two different databases

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two similar tables in two different databases in two different independent applications.  They all have a Members Table.  I want to be able to commit new member records in both databases when creating a new member in either of them.  That is to say if I insert  a new record in Table A of Database 1 I want same record in Table A of Database 2

I have created two database contexts connections in Config file.  In the controller how do I make this happen?

```
    public class MemberController : Controller
     {
    private ADb db = new ADb();
    private CDb db1 = new CDb();

public ActionResult Create(Member member, FormCollection collection, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
 using (ADb db = new ADb())
   {
     db.Members.Add(member);
     db.SaveChanges();
  }

 using (CDb db1 = new CDb())
  {
   member.fname= member.fname;
   member.Lname = member.Lname;
   db.Members.Add(member);
   db.SaveChanges();
  }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
}
```

Can this be achieved with this code above? Is there anything else I have to do? Do I have to duplicate the Model of the other Table? I need help to proceed.

Comment: One way would be to use automapper to map a viewmodel to each member class.

Comment: You could use SQL Server merge replication instead